# How do I count sections in a dataframe? - Create a Venn's Diagram

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I hope you can helps with this....
I needs to create a Venn's diagram from a table but I cannot find on how to sort out this.

I have the following table:

```
    id      type
0   44      A     
1   59      A    
2   59      B     
3   63      A       
4   63      C      
5   10      A       
6   10      B    
7   10      C
```

Then, I needs that this table looks like:

```
    new_t   Count
0   A       1
1   B       0
2   C       0
3   A-B     1
4   A-C     1
5   B-C     0
6   A-B-C   1
```

The problem is that I cannot find nothing on how to make it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (after doing speed testing in light of @ALollz solution, I decide to use `powerset` also) :

```
from itertools import combinations, chain
```

<strike>l = sum([list(combinations(df['type'].unique(),i)) for i in range(1,df['type'].nunique()+1)], [])</strike>

```
l = [x for x in powerset(df['type'].unique()) if x]

df_out = df.groupby('id')['type']\
           .agg(tuple)\
           .reset_index(drop=True)\
           .to_frame()\
           .set_index('type')\
           .assign(count=1)\
           .reindex(l, fill_value=0)

df_out.index = ['-'.join([x for x in i]) for i in df_out.index.tolist()]

df_out
```

Output:

```
       count
A          1
B          0
C          0
A-B        1
A-C        1
B-C        0
A-B-C      1
```

Answer (score 3):

If `['id', 'type']` is a unique key, this is `sort` then `groupby` + `str.join`. We'll take the powerset [recipe](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes) from itertools to get all of the combinations

```
from itertools import combinations, chain

def powerset(iterable):
    "powerset([1,2,3]) --> () (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3)"
    s = list(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)+1))
```

---

```
s = df.sort_values('type').groupby('id').agg('-'.join).groupby('type').size()

idx = ['-'.join(x) for x in powerset(df.type.unique()) if x]
s = s.reindex(idx).fillna(0, downcast='int)
```

#### Output: `s`

```
type
A        1
B        0
C        0
A-B      1
A-C      1
B-C      0
A-B-C    1
dtype: int32
```

Comment: "powerset"   Very very interesting... Thanks for a tool to add to my toolbox. +1

Comment: @ScottBoston yes I found myself reinventing the wheel several times, just to realize they have a whole list of useful ["recipes"](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes), powerset being the one I encounter most frequently